# getting error while sharding mongodb Unable to auto-split chunk

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

","msg":"Unable to auto-split chunk","attr":{"chunk":"[{ userId: MinKey }, { userId: -6666 })","namespace":"test","error":"Location4860101: Chunk to be auto split isn't owned by this shard"}}